# SQL injection for raw query in Room migration class

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room, sql-injection

OWASP tool gives warning of sql injection while writing raw sql query in Room migration. Is there any solution to overcome for this problem. Below is my code:

```
class Migration1to2 : Migration(1, 2) {
override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {

    database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Book ADD COLUMN pub_year INTEGER")
}
}
```